# How to define enum in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, enumeration

Is there a way to define an enum in AS3 in a way we do it in other languages? I can define constants with defined values like that:

```
private const CONST_1:int = 0;
private const CONST_2:int = 1;
private const CONST_3:int = 2;
```

and so on. If I want to insert some other constant between 3 these I need to move all values like that:

```
private const CONST_1:int = 0;
private const CONST_2:int = 1;
private const CONST_2A:int = 2;
private const CONST_3:int = 3;
```

while in other language I would end up with only adding a new member to enum closure like that:

```
enum {
    CONST_1 = 0,
    CONST_2,
    CONST_2A,
    CONST_3
} MyConstEnum;
```

Does AS3 has something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No AS3 doesn't have enum, you have to code them yourself. You can simulate them for example by a class if you want safer type checking.

Comment: I like the Scott Bilas method.

Comment: An implementation of the Bilas method from Cardin@github:
https://gist.github.com/cardin/1066674

Answer (score 12):

```
public static var NUM_ENUM_VALUES:int = 0;
public static const EV_MONDAY:int = NUM_ENUM_VALUES++;
public static const EV_TUESDAY:int = NUM_ENUM_VALUES++;
public static const EV_WEDNESDAY:int = NUM_ENUM_VALUES++;
public static const EV_THURSDAY:int = NUM_ENUM_VALUES++;
```

Answer (score 11):

You can take a look at the variety of variable types supported by the ActionScript Virtual Machine.  Variable types are annotated by *traits*, the variety of which can be found in the [specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/avm2overview.pdf#page=29), table 4.8.1:

```
4.8.1 Summary of trait types
The following table summarizes the trait types.

Type           Value
Trait_Slot       0
Trait_Method     1
Trait_Getter     2
Trait_Setter     3
Trait_Class      4
Trait_Function   5
Trait_Const      6
```

There is no `Trait_Enum` and note that under `Trait_Const` description, only constants from the *constant pool*  are allowed, so that would be:

- signed integers
- unsigned integers
- doubles
- strings
- type names and vector types

Enums could be made of signed or unsigned integers, for example, but the virtual machine would not perform any type-safety checking of the operations which used those types.  (E.g., the `getlocal` or `coerce` opcodes used would be `getlocal_i` and `coerce_i`, respectively.)

The ABC format doesn't have any built-in provision for enum types that I know of.

Using an object type for each enum value could work, especially if the compiler emits `coerce` instructions for that type prior to uses of `getlocal` and otherwise doesn't use the object other than in `istype` and `astype` variants.  For example, calling `setproperty` or `getproperty` on the object would be slower than using an integer -- especially if that property is bound to a getter or setter method.

There are replacement styles which have been linked in other answers.  To evaluate the runtime performance impact of these styles, you can uses `swfdump -D` from the [swftoools](http://swftools.org) open-source Flash tools collection.